# Wordpress widget: Checkbox not saving state

Tags: wordpress, checkbox, widget

I have a Wordpress widget with checkboxs. I am trying to set the default state to "checked" for one of the checkboxes by setting a variable in my defaults array to true. If I uncheck the box and try to save the widget the checkbox reverts back to being checked, so basically I can't uncheck the box.

I have other checkboxs with the same configuration and they are working correctly. Does anyone see anything wrong with my code below?

```
$defaults = array(
    'widget' => 'cat',
    'type' => 'list',
    'selected' => 0,
    'use_products' => 'true',
    'title' => '',
    'sub_title' => '',
    'operator' => 'IN',
    'print_before_widget' => 'true',
    'print_after_widget' => 'true',
    'hide_empty' => 'true',
    'hide_on_cats' => 'false',
    'custom_class' => ''
);

$instance = parse_args( $instance, $defaults );
extract( $instance );

<p>
<input class="checkbox"
        <?php if ( isset( $use_products ) && $use_products=='true' ) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>
        id = "<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'use_products' ); ?>"
        name = "<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'use_products' ); ?>"
        value = "true"
        type = "checkbox"
    />
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'use_products' ); ?>" ><?php _e( 'Show Product Categories', textdomain ); ?></label>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be several things wrong here but you may not be giving enough context.

I am assuming this is a snippet from inside the `form()` method of your widget. The form() method is passed the $instance variable, which contains the current values of all the widget settings. You dont appear to be using that at all. Your value for the checkbox is hardcoded as true, and your `$defaults` array isnt merged or overridden by anything - your just setting defaults and using them directly - your not using values from the database.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API#Default_Usage

Edit

---

In your update method, for the checkbox, you should do something like the following...

```
public function update($new_instance, $old_instance){

    $instance = array();

    $instance['checkbox_key'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['checkbox_key'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['checkbox_key'] ) : '';

    return $instance;
}
```

If this doesnt make sense in your context, you should update your answer to include the `update()` method.

Comment: Yes you are correct I left some code out and this is for the form method also. I updated it to show that I am merging the two arrays of parameters into $instance.

Comment: This works. However once I changed to using the update method I needed to add all the widget fields into the update method not just the product checkbox. But once that was done it works correctly.

Comment: `once I changed to using the update method I needed to add all the widget fields into the update method` Yeah, thats what I meant with the context. The version I provided was generic. Depending on how your handling the update method otherwise, there are different ways to do this. The point is simply that you need to explicitly define as empty/falst/null or unset the checkbox item in the array if its empty on $new_instance.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. How would you achieve this without using the update method?

Comment: You have to use the update method, but you don't necessarily have to name every single input key. You can use a for loop for example.